# Cannot cast enum to combobox value

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox bound to an enum (through a binding source). I'm populating the combobox as follows:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>(myEnum.Customer, "Customer"));

cbo.DataSource = list;
cbo.DisplayMember = "Value";
cbo.ValueMember = "Key";
```

And I also have this event:

```
private void cbo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbo.SelectedValue == null)
        return;

    var value = (KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>)cbo.SelectedValue;
    var item = (MyEnum)value.Key;

    if (item == MyEnum.Customer)
    { //Do someting... }
 }
```

However, I'm getting the exception:

> Specified cast is not valid

when setting `cbo.ValueMember`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `cbo.DataSource= Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))` have you tried something like this..?

Comment: @MethodMan I'm doing the above so that I display a different description than the enum.

Comment: Are you getting the error when setting the `ValueMember`, or when trying to cast the `SelectedValue`?

Comment: You're trying to cast the Selected value in the combo box to one of your KeyValue pairs... you're only going to get the key value back from cbo.SelectedValue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I recall correctly SelectedValue will only contain the Enum value in this case, as you have specified that the value is stored in the "Key" property with the line

```
cbo.ValueMember = "Key";
```

If you modify your code like this, it should work:

```
cbo.DisplayMember = "Value"; // Please note that it is important to set the DisplayMember 
cbo.ValueMember = "Key";     // and ValueMember before assigning the DataSource

var list = new List<KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>>();
list.Add(new KeyValuePair<MyEnum, string>(myEnum.Customer, "Customer"));
cbo.DataSource = list;
```

and

```
private void cbo_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cbo.SelectedValue == null)
        return;

    var item = (MyEnum)cbo.SelectedValue;

    if (item == MyEnum.Customer)
    { //Do someting... }
}
```

Comment: That was my original code before I changed it to the above. I get the exception throw at exactly: `var item = (MyEnum)cbo.SelectedValue;`

Comment: You are right, you will need to change the order of the lines in the top as well